# Metrics/Actuator not working in jHipster project after SpringBoot version upgrade

Tags: jhipster, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

**Project Details**:

1. Was generated with Jhipster 4.3.0
2. Now, SpringBoot version upgraded from 1.5.2 to 2.2.6

After SpringBoot version upgrade, Administration>Metrics does not work.

[image]

**Application.yml -Metrics**

```
management:
server:
    servlet:
       context-path: /management
endpoints:
   web:
      base-path: /management
      exposure:
          include: ['configprops', 'env', 'health', 'info', 'metrics', 'jhimetrics', 'logfile', 'loggers', 'prometheus', 'threaddump']
endpoint:
   jhimetrics:
      enabled: true
metrics:
   enable:
      http: true
      jvm: true
      logback: true
      process: true
      system: true
```

On hitting http://localhost:8080/management/metrics, I am getting following response:

```
{"names":[
  "cache.removals",
  "http.server.requests",
  "cache.evictions",
  "cache.gets",
  "process.start.time",
  "cache.puts",
  "http.server.requests.percentile",
  "jvm.threads.states",
  "jvm.memory.committed",
  "jdbc.connections.active",
  "jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
  "jvm.memory.max",
  "jvm.gc.pause.percentile",
  "jvm.gc.max.data.size",
  "jvm.gc.pause",
  "jdbc.connections.max",
  "jdbc.connections.min",
  "system.cpu.count",
  "logback.events",
  "jvm.memory.used",
  "jvm.threads.daemon",
  "jvm.buffer.memory.used",
  "system.cpu.usage",
  "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
  "jdbc.connections.idle",
  "jvm.threads.live",
  "jvm.threads.peak",
  "process.uptime",
  "process.cpu.usage",
  "jvm.classes.loaded",
  "jvm.classes.unloaded",
  "jvm.gc.live.data.size",
  "jvm.buffer.count",
  "jvm.buffer.total.capacity"]}
```

While I am expecting response like this:
[image]

I also tried to hit http://localhost:9999/management/jhimetrics, here I got 404 error.

Anyone encountered similar problem or any has solution? Please help.

Comment: What client framework are you using? Did you update JHipster to the latest version, or just Spring Boot?

Comment: I am using AngularJs. Only SpringBoot version is upgraded, not JHipster. Metrics were working before SpringBoot upgrade.

Comment: If you have updated from boot 1.x to 2.2.x the response format has changed. I think you have to adapt the client side code.